# Java HTTPServlet upload and delete file

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload, delete-file

what http methods are used in servlets to upload/delete files from server:

- POST
- GET
- PUT
- OPTIONS
- DELETE

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file you should use post and multipart request amd to delete - delete.

Comment: GET is meant to be idempotent.

Comment: we can't use delete to delete a file?

Comment: Get for files @Sotirios? Clearly not recomended. Get accepts much less request length than post.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Read about [idempotency](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2) in the HTTP specification. Don't delete with GET.

Comment: so, what was the conclusion? POST for upload and DELETE for deleting?

Answer (score 0):

Use PUT for uploads, DELETE for deletion.
Here is a nice answer with more details:[Which HTTP methods match up to which CRUD methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203231/which-http-methods-match-up-to-which-crud-methods)