# Is this how a 3 model REST/CRUD route should look? Is there too much going on in my routing? e.g. "/user/8/lesson/71/hotspot/893/edit"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 models: User, Lesson and Hotspot.  A lesson owns many hotspots, and a user owns many lessons.  In the future, I may allow users to have access to other user's lessons but that is a decision I'll make later.  So to create a new user, I go to "/user/create".  To create a new lesson, I go to "/user/1/create".  To create a new hotspot, I go to "/user/1/lesson/1/hotspot/create".  When I create a new hotspot, in my hotspot controller I have to ask "does the user own this?"  "does this lesson own this?" for every CRUD action, which means my hotspot controller has to know a little about user and lesson, which doesn't really feel right.

Am I doing this correctly, or am I incorrect?

Here are my routes (note: uid == user id, lid == lesson id, hid == hotspot id)

```
// User CRUD routes
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/user/create', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('/user/create', 'UserController@store');
Route::get('/user/{uid}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/edit', 'UserController@update');
Route::post('/user/edit', 'UserController@update');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/delete', 'UserController@destroy');
// Lesson CRUD routes
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/', 'LessonController@index');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/create', 'LessonController@create');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/create', 'LessonController@store');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}', 'LessonController@show');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/edit', 'LessonController@edit');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/edit', 'LessonController@update');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/edit', 'LessonController@update');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/delete', 'LessonController@destroy');
// Lesson CRUD routes
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot', 'HotspotController@index');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/create', 'HotspotController@create');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/create', 'HotspotController@store');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/{hid}', 'HotspotController@show');
Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/{hid}/edit', 'HotspotController@edit');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/{hid}/edit', 'HotspotController@update');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/{hid}/edit', 'HotspotController@update');
Route::post('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}/hotspot/{hid}/delete', 'HotspotController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nester resource.

Route::resource('user.lesson', LessonController');

You can go as deep as you like.

Comment: [Looking into this now](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).  I may have questions- will post back if I do.  This looks like it may be what I'm looking for- will accept as answer if it is.

Comment: DUDE!  It's BEAUTIFUL!

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('user.lesson', 'LessonController');
Route::resource('user.lesson.hotspot', 'HotspotController');

Comment: Very powerful hey :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're building some kind of an API.

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203231/which-http-methods-match-up-to-which-crud-methods) in mind you don't really need `/create`, `/edit` and `/delete` parts anywhere: all of this is solved by using appropriate HTTP methods.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should use the URL schema I'm suggesting but I need to readjust the HTTP verb words?

Comment: @AndrewAllbright If what you're building is a REST API, you don't really need a `GET /user/{uid}/edit` route. Rather, you need a `POST /users/` to create, `DELETE /users/{uid}` to delete, etc.

Comment: I can fix my REST Api... What about the url schema?  Is it good?

Edit: here is the fixed rest API

// User CRUD fixed
 Route::post('/user/');       // create
 Route::get('/user/{uid}');   // read
 Route::put('/user/{uid}');   // update
 Route::delete('/user/{uid}');// delete